# Find cube root in C

Tags: c, floating-point, double, root

I am trying to find cube root of the volume and it does not work well. I think there is a problem with the floating point but do not know how to fix it. As you can see cube root should be 3 not 37

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main() {
    int width;
    int length;
    int height;
    int volume;
    double volumes;

    printf("write width  ");
    scanf("%d", &width);

    printf("write length  ");
    scanf("%d", &length);

    printf("write height  ");
    scanf("%d", &height);


    volume = width * length * height;
    
    printf("volume is %d  \n", volume);

    volumes =  (double)pow((double)volume,1.0/ 3.0);

    printf("cube root is %f   \n", volumes);

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Images should only be used when there is no other way to demonstrate an issue, and text content from the console or terminal can be copied and pasted (or typed) directly into your post.

Comment: You'll need to put the line `#include <math.h>`.

Comment: C has a standard [`cbrt()` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/cbrt)... No need to mess with `pow()`.

Comment: Running your code as is (ignoring warnings) I get the correct answer (3) you expected. Treat warnings as errors and you will not be surprised by your results. The warnings is an indication that the compiler is going to take a guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use cbrt() function in math.h file

```
#include<math.h>

//cbrt(x) to get cube root of x :)
    
printf("cube root is %f   \n",cbrt(x));
```